# Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Microsoft acquired Xamarin and announced that it was now part of Visual Studio. When I go Xamarin's website and click "Pricing", it reads "Contact Us for Quote" under Visual Studio Professional and Enterprise.

Is Xamarin NOT free for users of Visual Studio 2015 Pro/Enterprise?

Comment: That is for purchasing Visual Studio Professional/Enterprise if you are not legally eligible for the "free community edition of Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio", not the Xamarin platform. If you already own Pro/Ent licenses, just install Xamarin and start coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is included with all editions of VS.  But the Pro/Enterprise editions of VS are NOT free.  Pricing for those editions varies, that's why they tell you to contact them.

Comment: Don't you hate this: two contradictory answers. Yours and SushiHangover's. Yours seem more right though. Otherwise, why would they put contact us on Xamarin's website?

Comment: Their answers are not contradictory. You have to BUY VS Pro/Ent. It's not free. There is a free Community Edition of VS if you quality(and most do). Xamarin is free of charge with no limitations. You pay for VS.

Comment: Oh I see. I misinterpreted Jason's comments. I get it now. Thank you!